# How do you show that a particular matrix product has a general eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same size such that $B$ is invertible. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B^{-1}AB$.

[image]

**My (very scrappy) working/thinking so far:**

Know that $Av=\lambda v \implies B^{-1}ABv=B^{-1}(\lambda v)=\lambda (B^{-1}v)$

I also tried defining $v$ in terms of a new eigenvector $x$: Let
$B^{-1}ABx=Av \implies ABx=BAv \implies x=A^{-1}BAvB^{-1} \implies B^{-1}ABx=\lambda A^{-1}BAvB^{-1}$ and now I'm stuck.

I then tried defining $B^{-1}AB$ in terms of some $nxn$ matrix $S$ of the same size as $A$ and $B$ such that $S=B^{-1}AB$
$\implies A=BSB^{-1}$. Now, since $Av=λv \implies BSB^{-1}v = λv$.

I have thus shown that λ is an eigenvalue of $BSB^{-1}$, but am unsure how to relate this to $B^{-1}AB$, the intended matrix.

It feels like I am either missing out on some property of eigenvalue/eigenvectors that I could use.

Comment: Also, how do I get my TeX symbols to show through? I cannot seem to find the solution, so I have temporarily attached a screenshot of the original question.

Comment: You need to put dollar symbols around the math text. I edited your post, you can now look at the code to see what to do next time. Also, you may want to give your thoughts on, and attempts at, the problem else it is likely to be closed for a lack of effort.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then what is $(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}v)$?

Answer (score 1):

Because $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v}$.

Using the fact that $B$ is invertible (so that $BB^{-1} = I$) we can write

\begin{equation*}
ABB^{-1}\mathbf{v} = A\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}.
\end{equation*}

Then, multiplying on the left by $B^{-1}$, we have

\begin{equation*}
\left(B^{-1}AB\right)B^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \lambda B^{-1}\mathbf{v},
\end{equation*}

so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B^{-1}AB$ corresponding to the eigenvector $B^{-1}\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: I see, thank you! Totally forgot that I could treat $B^{-1}v$ as a new eigenvector

Comment: @JasonXu cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

$$ \det(B^{-1}AB- \lambda I)= \det (B^{-1}(A - \lambda I)B)= \det(B^{-1}) \det (A- \lambda I)  \det(B)=\det (A- \lambda I) .$$

Hence $(ii)$ follows from $(i)$.